# Sort image files based on luminance/brightness

Tags: python, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

I have taken one of my photo and applied 30 different artist patterns through Neural Art (deepart.io). This step generated 30 different photos. I have sliced each photo into 30 pieces horizontally. Now I want to pick each slice based on the increasing luminance/brightness. How can I do it python or imagemagick?

Comment: Please include some code to show what you have tried.

Comment: I have code for splitting a image into n horizontal pieces and also a code to join by randomly picking a slice of image from i position. But the output is not uniform. I've not tried anything wrt to luminance because I am new to image processing.

Answer (score 1):

Using ImageMagick, I can create a 1024x1024 black-white gradient and chop it up into 30 horizontal slices like this:

```
convert -size 1024x1024 gradient:black-white -crop x30@ slice-%02d.png
```

[image]

Now, I can convert each slice to HSL colorspace and split out the channels, discard Hue and Saturation leaving just Lightness and get the average of each slice's Lightness at the Terminal prompt like this:

```
for f in slice*; do 
   convert $f -colorspace hsl -separate -delete 0,1 -resize 1x1 -format "%[mean] %f\n" info:
done | sort -n

1057 slice-00.png
3235 slice-01.png
5413 slice-02.png
7623 slice-03.png
9833 slice-04.png
12012 slice-05.png
14190 slice-06.png
16368 slice-07.png
18546 slice-08.png
20724 slice-09.png
22902 slice-10.png
25112 slice-11.png
27322 slice-12.png
29500 slice-13.png
31678 slice-14.png
33857 slice-15.png
36035 slice-16.png
38213 slice-17.png
40423 slice-18.png
42633 slice-19.png
44811 slice-20.png
46989 slice-21.png
49167 slice-22.png
51345 slice-23.png
53523 slice-24.png
55702 slice-25.png
57912 slice-26.png
60122 slice-27.png
62300 slice-28.png
64478 slice-29.png
```

The values are scaled on the range [0-65535] because I am using a 16-bit ImageMagick version - i.e. Q16 when I run `identify -version`.

Answer (score 0):

The code below could work. It converts each PNG image to RGB, then to LAB color mode. It then computes the average lightness of the picture.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageCms
import glob

for fn in glob.glob("*.png"):
    im = Image.open(fn).convert("RGB")
    psRGB = ImageCms.createProfile("sRGB")
    pLab = ImageCms.createProfile("LAB")
    t = ImageCms.buildTransform(psRGB, pLab, "RGB", "LAB")
    imi = ImageCms.applyTransform(im, t)

    total_lightness = 0
    w, h = im.size
    for y in xrange(h):
        for x in xrange(w):
            l, a, b = imi.getpixel((x, y))
            total_lightness += l
    avg_lightness = total_lightness / (w * h)

    print "Average lightness of %s is %d" % (fn, avg_lightness)
```